# ReferenceError: variable is not defined (fullcalendar)

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, fullcalendar

I'm using Arshaw fullcalendar. When a time is selected it prompts for a name and email. I want to save these into variables and POST to my database.
This is the code I have, but when I try to POST it I get 'ReferenceError: email is not defined'. What am I doing wrong? How should I define email?

```
$(document).ready ->

calendar = $("#calendar")
calendar.fullCalendar
header: (left: 'title', center: '', right: 'today prev, next, agendaWeek, agendaDay')

events: 
  url: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/mycalendarfeeds/'

selectable: true
selectHelper: true

select: (start, end) ->
  name = prompt("Name:")
  email = prompt("Email:")
  if name && email
    calendar.fullCalendar "renderEvent",
      title: name
      start: start
      end: end
    true
  calendar.fullCalendar "unselect"

  $.ajax '/events',
    type: "POST"
    data: event: { name: name, email: email, start: start, end: end }
    success: () -> console.log("SUCCESS")
    dataType: "json"
```

calendar_controller.rb

```
require 'google_calendar'

class CalendarController < ApplicationController

def index
    @events = calendar.events
end

def create
    event_params = params[:event]

    @event = calendar.create_event do |e|
        e.name = event_params[:name]
        e.email = event_params[:email]
        e.start = Time.parse( event_params[:start] )
        e.end = Time.parse( event_params[:end] )
    end
    respond_to do |format|
        if @event.save
            format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Reservation saved" }
            format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
        else
            format.html {
                flash.now[:notice]= "Not able to make the reservation"
                render :create
            }
            format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

In a determinate moment this variable not receive a information or receive a diferent type.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you be more specific please?